# How many balls must a woman select from $10$ red balls and $10$ blue balls to be sure of having at least three balls of the same color?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

A bowl contains $10$ red balls and $10$ blue balls. A woman selects balls at random without looking at them.  How many balls must she select to be sure of having at least three balls of the same color?

Comment: What are your thoughts ?

Comment: What do you think is the worst possible scenario?

Comment: This was asked (as well as another variation dealing with specific color) in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/692870/a-bowl-contains-10-red-balls-and-10-blue-balls-a-women-selects-ball-at-random-w?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

5, she can get 2 of each color if she picks 4 balls at random.  So by choosing one more ball she would guarantee having 3 of one color.